# Déjà-vu answer, or a blatant case of reposting a deleted post?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers

There's something strange going on with [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/274161/78942) (visible to 10k+ users only). I seem to recall reading exactly the same answer written by the same users some days ago. It received some comments about the aether theory, and got negative rep. Nevertheless, the current answer is dated some minutes ago.

I don't think that this is some kind of déjà-vu. I highly suspect that the original answer was deleted, and then it war repost word-by-word by the same user. I can't check my suspicions since I don't have 10k rep and I can't see deleted posts. Note that this is different from [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7209/), since the deleted and new answers are the same (iirc).

Can anyone have a look at this?

Comment: I think you're right Bosoneando. But the guy has only answered 2 questions, so it might be just some kind of mistake.

Comment: @JohnDuffield Care to clarify that comment? The user in question has four questions and 56 answers, and I really don't think "s/he is unfamiliar with the site mechanics" applies at all. Or what do you mean by "mistake"?

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty : agreed. Sorry, I must have made some mistake in looking up the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, there [is a deleted post that is exactly the same](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/273121/50583) (only visible to >10k users). I have flagged the reposted answer for moderator attention.

Comment: FWIW I'd note that the original deleted post wasn't _exactly_ the same, but it was very close.