# Is this (meta question) in scope for meta?

Tags: discussion

Is [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9064/9887) meta question in scope for meta?

Tthe general question of "Is reposting a deleted answer acceptable?" is clearly in scope.

But it isn't clear to me that the linked question is.  It seems plausible that "Can someone look have a look at this?" type questions aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. It's about the site itself, which generally speaking puts it in scope for meta, and we don't have any rules against such questions that would override that.

If people start posting a lot of these questions, to the point where they overwhelm other meta posts, then we might have to change that. But as it is, they're quite rare.

Comment: Take this question, for example. Do we *really* benefit from the community bot bumping this up? I read this thread as fully resolved, *including* the vote counts (Q+2, A+0 at writing), but the bot bumping algorithm knows nothing of that.